# ESP-01 not responding to serial data while programming with esptool.py

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have a Arduino uno board, ESP-01 board and a logic level shifter (bidirectional) and to program the esp module i wired my Arduino and esp like this

> **Arduino uno(atmega328p removed)**  --> **level shifter** --> **ESP-01**
> 5v --> highvolt
> 3v3 --> lowvolt
> TX --> ch1 --> TX
> RX --> ch2 --> RX
> proper ground connections

but when i click upload the RX pin lights up indicating its receiving data but esp doesn't respond to that when i reset the module while its uploading the compiler throws this

```
Serial port COM3
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TRAJU\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "C:/Users/TRAJU/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main
    esp.connect(args.before)
  File "C:/Users/TRAJU/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect
    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
_
the selected serial port _
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

It as working fine yesterday and it stopped today :(

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem.

esptool.py uploads the firmware at 115200 baud rate, which my logic level converter couldn't handle.  I found this out after writing this question. I thought of connecting RX and RX directly to the ESP module's RX and TX and it uploaded the program. Maybe I am wrong.  Please, if any one know why this happened I am curios to know.  Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: Please accept this as the soulution, because the question is answered now.

Comment: It will take a day or two before you can do that.

Comment: Re: "if any one know why this happened", I would put a scope on it an look at the signals, particularly the rising edges because you may have something based roughly on [this design](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10441.pdf).  Questions about that belong more squarely on [ASE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), though you can probably work it out if my suspicions about the relevance of the appnote happen to be correct.  You *should* be doing *something* to address 5V -> 3.3V, rather than *nothing* in any case.

Comment: @timemage if i had a scope i wouldn't post this question at all, i could debug it myself (i wish i had a scope) and ya it says it takes around two days to accept my answer